# Building a Conda noarch package with python 2.7

Tags: python, conda

I have some code in Python 2.7, I want to make a Conda package for it ; the code is `noarch` in the sense that it can work on Windows or Linux for example. How can I build a Conda package that is both `noarch` and only installable in Python 2.7 environments ?

The `meta.yaml` is like this (unrelevant lines removed):

```
build:
    noarch: python

requirements:
    run:
       - python 2.7
```

But this does not work: the package depends on Python 3.

I noticed that removing `noarch` makes it working for Python 2 only, as expected. Strange isn't it?

Comment: Are you missing your `conda_build_config.yaml` build matrix where you specify the version of Python?

Answer (score 2):

Create both files in the same directory as your shell and then execute `conda build .`

**meta.yaml**

```
requirements:
    build:
       - python {{ python }}
    run:
       - python
```

**conda_build_config.yaml**

```
python:
    - 2.7
```

Comment: thanks for your help - I will check this asap. I didn't know about `conda_build_config.yaml` I thought it was all defined in `meta.yaml`

Comment: Same result with the `conda_build_config.yaml` file apparently - so, it seems it is impossible to make a `noarch` package with Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#architecture-independent-packages

> For pure Python packages that can run on **any Python version**, you can
>   use the `noarch: python` value

Then i guess the `noarch` have to be removed.

Comment: so Conda confuses architecture and Python version?!

Comment: @mguijarr -- it would appear so.  I am new to conda-build.  trying to build my pure python package with noarch.  it should only be supported for python 3.6 and higher, but it appears no way to do that with noarch.  I may have to use conda convert to all architectures if I want to specify the valid python version. See also: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5971